# Not thread safe class

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Why below class is not thread safe ?

```
public class UnsafeCachingFactorizer implements Servlet {
    private final AtomicReference<BigInteger> lastNumber = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final AtomicReference<BigInteger[]> lastFactors = new AtomicReference<>();

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        if i.equals(lastNumber.get())) {
            encodeIntoResponse(resp, lastFactors.get());
        }
        else {
            BigInteger[] factors = factor(i);
            lastNumber.set(i);
            lastFactors.set(factors);
            encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
        }
    }
}
```

Instance variables are thread safe, then why the whole class is not thread safe ?

Comment: Because you don't check and set `lastFactors` and `lastNumbers` atomically.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Both instance veriables are atomically gaurded. So the moment next thread try to access any of the variable, Wouldnt it'll wait until its ready to be accessed ?

Comment: a call to `get()` is atomic; a call to `set(...)` is atomic. But they are not atomic together. This is why there are methods like `getAndSet(...)`, `compareAndSet(...)` etc.

Comment: But even in that case, the sequence will remain Atomic.Get and then Set. So even next thread arrives, will follow the same sequence, and it won’t be able to reach set until get is done, which is already acquired by first thread. Nope ?

Comment: they follow the same sequence within each thread, but there's nothing to stop the threads' actions interleaving.

Comment: If they follow same seq within thread, Then sir what’s a point of making them atomic. .? I’m mean If something is atomic, process is reserved for altering, and won’t allow next one to alter until its finished ...!

Comment: "what's the point of making them atomic" here, there is no point in making them atomic, because the code is broken, because you're not using them correctly (because multiple actions on atomic things aren't atomic). It is differently broken to if they weren't atomic, but differently broken is still broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not thread safe because you don't always get the right answer when multiple threads call the code.

Let's say that `lastNumber=1` and `lastFactors=factors(1)`. In the one-thread case, where the thread calls with `i=1`:

```
T1: if (lastNumber.get().equals(1)) { // true
T1:   encodeIntoResponse(resp, lastFactors.get());
```

Fine, this is the expected result. But consider a multi-threaded case, where the actions within each thread takes place in the same order, but can arbitrarily interleave. One such interleaving is (where `i=1` and `i=2` for the two threads respectively):

```
T1: if (lastNumber.get().equals(1)) { // true

T2: if (lastNumber.get().equals(2)) { // false
T2: } else {
T2:   lastNumber.set(2);
T2:   lastFactors.set(factors(2));

T1:   encodeIntoResponse(resp, lastFactors.get()); // oops! You wrote the factors(2), not factors(1).
```

The problem is that you're not getting and setting the AtomicReferences atomically: that is, there is nothing to stop another thread sneaking in and changing the values (of one or either) between the get and the set.

In general, whilst individual calls to methods on an `AtomicReference` are atomic, multiple calls are not (and they definitely aren't atomic between instances of `AtomicReference`). So, if you ever find yourself writing code like:

```
if (/* some condition with ref.get() */) {
  /* some statement with ref.set() */
}
```

then you *probably* aren't using `AtomicReference` correctly (or, at least, it's not thread-safe).

To fix this, you need something that can be read and set atomically. For example, create a simple class to hold both:

```
class Holder {
  // Add a ctor to initialize these.
  final BigInteger number;
  final BigInteger[] factors;
}
```

Then store this in a single AtomicReference, and use `updateAndGet`:

```
BigInteger[] factors = holderRef.updateAndGet(h -> {
  if (h != null && h.number.equals(i)) {
    return h;
  }
  return new Holder(i, factor(i));
}).factors;
encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
```

---

Upon reflection, `updateAndGet` isn't necessarily the right way to do this. If `factors` sometimes takes a long time to compute, then a long-time computation might get done many times, because lots of other shorter-time computations preempt it, so the update function keeps having to be called.

Instead, you can just always set the reference if you had to recompute it:

```
Holder h = holderRef.get();
if (h == null || !h.number.equals(i)) {
  h = new Holder(i, factors(i));
  holderRef.set(h);
}
return h.factors;
```

This may seem to violate what I said previously, in that separate calls to `holderRef` are not atomic, and thus not thread-safe.

It's a bit more nuanced, however: my first paragraph states that the lack of thread safety in the original code stems from the fact that you might get the factors for the wrong input. This problem doesn't occur here: you either get the holder for the right number (and hence the factors for the right number), or you compute the factors for the input.

The issue arises in what this holder is actually meant to be storing: the "last" number/factors is rather hard to define in terms of multithreading. When are you measuring "last-ness" from? The most recent call to start? The most recent call to finish? Other?

This code simply stores "a" previously computed value, without attempting to nail down this ambiguity.

Comment: Isn’t it weird ? If two thread going to reach atomic instance variables via nonAtomic method, then there is possibility of not getting correct value. Don’t you think so, Atomic holder should pause next coming thread until it’s completed, even it’s coming from nonAtmic method ..? Atomic type’s duty is not to attend new work until work is finished which is in hand already. Did I say wrong ..?

Comment: Your expectations of `Atomic` holder types do not match how they actually work.  What you need to do is to read the javadocs, etc to find out how they actually do work.  If your mental model is incorrect, then you won't be able to use them correctly.  (Your statements about the "duty" of these classes is wishful thinking, not fact.)